# Translating login form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have simple login form. Session is not a model, just controller to do authentication and save cookie to remember user.

```
<%= form_for(:session, url:sessions_path, html:{id:"login_form"}) do |f| %>
  <div>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div>
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Login" %>
<%end%>
```

I want to traslate this `:email` and `:password` labels, for models I know how to do it:

```
activerecord:
  attributes:
    user:
      password: Hasło
      name: Login
      password_digest: Potwierdzenie hasła
```

But here I have no idea under what keys should I put it.

Answer (score 0):

I changed this label line to:

`<%= f.label :password,t("activerecord.attributes.user.password") %>`

It works, but I'm not sure if it's the best way.

Comment: This gets to the basics, but consider following the patterns suggested in the Rails guide (I linked in my answer above) to make your life easier as well as the people who follow and maintain your code :-)

Comment: I changed translation to `t(".password")` and put trasnlation in sessions.new.password. Is this better?

Answer (score 0):

Rails is fully set up for [localization and internationalization, guide linked here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

The usual location for internationalized files is `config/locales/<language-code>.yml`.  Use the `t` method of the I18N class to look up the key in the file and return the value to be displayed in the correct language.

There's also a [Railscast on I18N](http://railscasts.com/episodes/138-i18n) although it's a little outdated, most likely.

Comment: I did it. Read guides twice, and watched revised railcast :). I know I can do it the way I answered my post. I thought if I use just `f.label :password` there is some 'magic' keys path, so I wont have to add additional t() parameter to label method.

Comment: Well, having done I18N in C, C++, Java and several other languages, this is about as close to magic as I have ever seen :-).  The magic path is the `config/locales`.  You don't need to make very long keys like `activerecord.attributes.user.password` -- `user.password` (following the structure of your models) is probably sufficient.  And to save a few more characters, lose the parenthesis and use lazy lookup where possible, as `<%= f.label :password, t '.password'` %>